# Error in feching message from gmail api with multiple queries

Tags: gmail-api

I want to get unread mails from yesterday. So i had to implement multiple queries in the  message.list function which give me an error of invalid syntax. How do i do it? Can someone help me? And will internalDate help me anyway?

```
 from __future__ import print_function
    import httplib2
    import os
    from email.utils import parsedate_tz,mktime_tz,formatdate
    from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
    import datetime
    from datetime import date,timedelta
    import time
    from apiclient import discovery
    import oauth2client
    from oauth2client import client
    from oauth2client import tools
    import json
    try:
        import argparse
        flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
    except ImportError:
        flags = None

    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_server.json'
    APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Quickstart'
    def get_credentials():
        """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

        If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
        the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

        Returns:
            Credentials, the obtained credential.
        """
        home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
        credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
        if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
            os.makedirs(credential_dir)
        credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                       'gmail-python-quickstart.json')

        store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
        credentials = store.get()
        if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
            flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
            if flags:
                credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
            else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
                credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
            print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
        return credentials

    def main():

        da=date.fromordinal(730920)
        credentials = get_credentials()
        http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
        today=date.today()
        print (today)
        yesterday=today-timedelta(1)
        print (yesterday) 

       response = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',q='{in:inbox is:unread} AND {after: {0}.format(yesterday.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))}').execute()

        messages=[]
        store=[]
        message1=[]
        test2=[]
        da=[]
        if 'messages' in response:
         messages.extend(response['messages'])
        fo = open("foo.txt", "wb")


        for i in range(len(messages)):

         store=messages[i]['id']
         message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me',id=store,format='metadata',metadataHeaders=['from','date']).execute()
         fo.write(store+" ");
         #print(message['payload']['headers'][0])
         fo.write(message['snippet'].encode('utf-8')+" ")
         if message['payload']['headers'][0]['name'].lower()=="from":
          From=message['payload']['headers'][0]['value']
          fo.write(From+" ");
         elif message['payload']['headers'][0]['name'].lower()=="date":
          da=message['payload']['headers'][0]['value']

          fo.write(da+"\n");

         for line in open("foo.txt"):
          print(line)

          # Open a file
    # Close opend file
        fo.close()



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
q='in:inbox is:unread newer_than:3d'
```

as the query. Gmail queries don't have a concept of timezones so if you try to get one day worth of email you'll end up with some overlap. Just use local filtering to narrow those down. See [advanced Gmail search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) for more help. The API and Gmail UI use the same query syntax and should show the same results so you can do testing in the UI.